# NodeJS version in linux Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I want to change the `NodeJS` version in the Linux Azure function. (`ElasticPremium`)

I only have one version in general settings.

[image: Stack Settings]

I also tried `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` in applications settings but nothing changed.

[image: application settings]

is there any solution to change the NodeJS version in Azure functions?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#setting-the-node-version), `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is only for function apps running on Windows. For Linux, you need to use Azure API in one form or the other to change the Node.js version.

It's weird you don't see the options in the UI, it works for me (Linux Premium too). Another glitch in Azure. Anyway, here's how you can update the version programmatically:

With Azure CLI:

```sh
az functionapp config set --linux-fx-version "node|12" --name "<MY_APP_NAME>" --resource-group "<MY_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
```

With ARM template:

```json
{
    ...
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "properties": {
        ...
        "siteConfig": {
            ...
            "linuxFxVersion": "node|12"
        }
    }
}
```

With Terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  ...
  site_config {
    ...
    linux_fx_version = "node|12"
  }
```

As of Feb 20, 2021, available versions are:

```
node|10
node|12 (recommended)
node|14 (preview)
```

Comment: Detailed guide here: https://www.maxivanov.io/change-nodejs-version-in-azure-functions/